# Confusing application of DCT

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I need to apply DCT to bring the limit inside the abslute value...

$\displaystyle \lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0}  \left\lbrace  \sum_{z \in \mathcal{E}} \mid a_z \mid ^2  \left(\int_{B_{R}} \left|\frac{1}{\sigma(U(z,\tau))}\int_{U(z,\tau) }  e^{ ix \cdot \xi}\,d{\sigma \left( \xi\right) }\right|^p \,dx\right)  ^\frac{2}{p} \right\rbrace  ^\frac{1}{2}$

where $\mathcal{E}$ is a discrete set of points , $B_{R}$ is the ball in $\mathbb{R}^n $ of radius $R$.

$a_z$ are some constants.

$U(z,\tau)$ is a neighborhood of $z$.

Is there any reason why I can't write

$\displaystyle \lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0}  \left\lbrace  \sum_{z \in \mathcal{E}} \mid a_z \mid ^2  \left(\int_{B_{R}} \left|\frac{1}{\sigma(U(z,\tau))}\int_{U(z,\tau) }  e^{ ix \cdot \xi}\,d{\sigma \left( \xi\right) }\right|^p \,dx\right)  ^\frac{2}{p} \right\rbrace  ^\frac{1}{2} = \left\lbrace  \sum_{z \in \mathcal{E}} \mid a_z \mid ^2  \left(\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0}\int_{B_{R}} \left|\frac{1}{\sigma(U(z,\tau))}\int_{U(z,\tau) }  e^{ ix \cdot \xi}\,d{\sigma \left( \xi\right) }\right|^p \,dx\right)  ^\frac{2}{p} \right\rbrace  ^\frac{1}{2}$

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write is correct provided the discrete set is finite, since $x^{1/2}$  and $x^{2/p}$ are continuous functions. If that set is infinite, then generally no.

Comment: It's a discrete set on some compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$, whose points are separated by some constant... Then it is actually finite right?

Comment: Yes. Any discrete set in a compact Hausdorff space is finite.